# How to make a Spinnaker SpEL reference to a context attribute that does not exist return null (or None or '')?

Tags: spinnaker

According to [Spinnaker Doc](https://spinnaker.io/guides/user/pipeline/expressions/), a context value for attribute X can be referenced as **${#stage("Deploy to Prod")["X"]}**.
In my case, X may not exist. The value returned when X does not exist is the SpEL expression itself "${#stage("Deploy to Prod")["X"]}". I was expecting to get a null or empty string.
Is there a way to get the SpEL expression return None or '' when the attribute does not exist in the context map?

Answer (score 3):

Try the Elvis operator:

```
${ #stage("Deploy to Prod")["X"]?:"defaultValue" }
```

The Elvis operator `?:` can be used to get a value if exists - in the example: `#stage("Deploy to Prod")["X"]` -, else get the default value - in the example: `"defaultValue"`.
Explanation from [SpEL docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html), section "6.5.14 The Elvis Operator":

> The Elvis operator is a shortening of the ternary operator syntax and is used in the Groovy language. With the ternary operator syntax you usually have to repeat a variable twice, for example:
>
> ```
> String name = "Elvis Presley";
> String displayName = name != null ? name : "Unknown";
> ```